# How can we show $gnu(8892)=gnu(9324)$ by hand?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

With GAP it can be verified immediately that there are $303$ groups of order $8892=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 13\cdot19$ and also $303$ groups of order $9324=2^2\cdot3^2\cdot 7\cdot 37$.

I do not expect that the number $303$ can be calculated by hand, but perhaps it can be shown by looking at the prime factorizations and using Sylow's theorem, that the number of groups is the same for both orders.

I found out that a group of order $8892$ must have exactly one subgroup of order $13$ and a group of order $9324$ must have exactly one subgroup of order $37$. I do not know whether this helps.

Maybe it is possible to establish a $1-1$ correspondence between a group of order $8892$ and a group of order $9324$, but I have no idea how that can be made.

Comment: Note that the pairs of prime factors $(7,19)$ and $(37,13)$ differ by multiples of $\varphi(2^2\cdot3^2)=12$.

Comment: Note also  that, by Sylow's Theorem, a group of order $8892$ must have a normal subgroup $C_{13} \times C_{19}$. You can prove by a counting argument that a group of order $36 \times 7$ cannot have $36$ Sylow $7$-subgroups, so a group of order $9324$ must have a normal subgroup $C_7 \times C_{37}$. So the groups of the two orders are just corresponding semidirect products of these normal subgroups with a group order $36$.

Comment: both are cubefree - one should look for relevant information in the literature on groups of cubefree order.

Comment: Following on from my previous comments, the automorphism groups of $C_{13\times 19}$ and $C_{7 \times 37}$ are both isomorphic to $C_6 \times C_{36}$, so it is not surprising that the semidirect products correspond exactly.